# How to limit an each loop on json data in jquery ?

Tags: jquery, json, each

Is there a nice way to loop on only the first 3 items of a json object using the jquery each loop?

I am thinking of an equivalent of the [.slice(start,end)](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) function.

```
var data = [ 
 {"Id": 10004, "PageName": "club"}, 
 {"Id": 10040, "PageName": "qaz"}, 
 {"Id": 10059, "PageName": "ee"}, 
 {"Id": 10089, "PageName": "dd"}, 
 {"Id": 10095, "PageName": "hh"}
];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(item.PageName);
    // somehow break at item 3
});​
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
var data = [ 
 {"Id": 10004, "PageName": "club"}, 
 {"Id": 10040, "PageName": "qaz"}, 
 {"Id": 10059, "PageName": "ee"}, 
 {"Id": 10089, "PageName": "dd"}, 
 {"Id": 10095, "PageName": "hh"}
];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(item.PageName);
    return i<2;
});​
```

each stops when you return false.

From the docs:

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
$.each(data.slice(0,3), function(i, item) {
    alert(item.PageName);
});​
```

Comment: Is this faster than simply stopping the loop after `3 increments of i?`

Comment: It should not matter for small json objects.. What if your json object has large amount of data.. If thta's the case you are needlessly looping thru

Comment: I agree completely about your statement; I just asked out of curiosity incase you knew.

Comment: This works if the each is applied to a JSON array. Otherwise it fails with: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'slice'

It would fail if data = { "key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":"value4","key5":"value5" }

Comment: Yes that's true.. It woeks here cause it is an array of objects

Answer (score 3):

You may try this

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    if(i>2) return false;
    alert(item.PageName);
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/erdjw/1/).

Comment: Well, that will iterate all elements in the array.

Comment: @VisioN No it won't. See the details in aquinas's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($(data).slice(0,3), function(i,item){
  console.log("\t",item.Id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to loop through it using a for-loop

here's how it's done

```
     for(var i =0;i<3;i++){

       alert("Id is"+d[i].id) ;

     }
```

And to loop through the whole Json array use the following

```
      for(var i =0;i<d.length;i++){

         alert("Id is"+d[i].id);
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$.each(data, function(i){
  //i is 0 based, so 3 is really 2.
  if(i == 2){
      //exit the loop on the 3rd iteration of the object.
      return false;
  }
});
```